Finiteness of the intersection number
I am taking a course on Algebraic Curves following Gathmann and I am trying to solve exercise 2.7(b) which reads as follows:
$F,G$ two curves with no common components through the origin, then every element of $\mathscr{O}_0/(F,G)\mathscr{O}_0$ has a polynomial representative.
In the previous section I have proved that $x^n, y^n\in(F,G)\mathscr{O}_0$ for some n, but I don't know how to use it now.
